# Drools, What is the best practice to consult a very large history

Tags: java, service, drools

Hello I have the following problem and I wanted to know if Drools gives me an option to handle it.

I have a 200k work order and I want to compare it against all work orders in the last 30 days (900k) and determine if a set of conditions are met.

The question would be what is the best way to apply DROOLS:

1- I must obtain from the BD the last 30 work orders with a service and then provide it to Drools for comparison.

2- Is there any way within the rule (DRL) to obtain the work orders of the last 30 days for that client.

Comment: [There are good practices in context, but there are no best practices.](https://context-driven-testing.com/)

Comment: Drools isn't a database. It doesn't know about how your store your data. You can't "use it" to get your historical work orders. If you want to use rules to evaluate your work orders, you'll need to provide the rules with those work orders.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a database to extract the minimal amount of information you need to apply your custom logic and eventually write a series of rules to apply your business domain.

The database will be surely faster to extract the data, but if you need these rules to be authored by non-technical users or you have a lot of business logic  you might find some advantages in writing your business logic using DRL.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `spark` + `HBase` + `java streams`
We had quite interesting project to rewrite ~ 40 SQL rules residing deep inside Oracle DB and expose it to business as lovely DSL rules on drools business central.
Producer was scanning HBase index of transaction ids for the day and passed that batch through the `Kafka` to clustered spark processing app which executed rules on each doing any required historical lookups (running rules over that stream) and sent results to consumer app which persisted results back to Oracle. Producer and Processor apps were running on a Spark cluster using 4 machines (40 CPU each), consumer was ordinal Spring app.
Original SQL rules were about 50-100 lines business nightmare and the whole batch was executed in about 20 - 40 minutes on Oracle DB before business day started. We made it 7-8 mins. producing exactly the same output in result tables. Distributed team ~7 persons in average during project period did it in about a year.
Problems we faced: each rule was a headache because each business rule logic is very data structure dependent. You must prepopulate index tables when you generate historical data (the job Oracle usually do for you). You must process data in streams because data volumes are terabytes.
Why it was possible: HBase get by id operation is very fast. Code is transferred where the data is located not the opposite like in traditional app (any map-reduce clustered solution prime idea). High parallelism, and huge processing power do their job. You always process stream of data not to be dependent on the size of any scan result.
In practice we had rules to filter irrelevant transactions and then java method in drools then block which was doing actual historical scan and processing. That java history lookup method was represented as DSL statement with business meaning. Result of history lookup was sent straight to consumer or you can write another rule on top of that data stream.